# How do I update the screen (canvas) of a Tkinter window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have searched quite extensively and haven't found the answer.

I have tracked down and reduced my problem to this example.

```
from Tkinter import *

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = True

obj = A()

def meth():
    obj.var = False
    paintGui()

def paintGui():    
    master = Tk()
    w = Canvas(master, width=200, height=100)
    w.pack()
    w.create_rectangle(50, 25, 150, 75, fill="blue", tags="rect")

    btn = Button(master, text="Cerrar Mesa",command=meth)
    btn.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    if obj.var == False:
        w.itemconfig("rect", fill="red")

    mainloop()

paintGui()
```

As you can see the rectangle has a conditional `itemconfig`.

The line `paintGui()` inside `meth()` is only to show that the code is working and when `obj.var` is `False` then it is turning to red.

My problem is that the original window (the one underneath it) is still blue.

I could kill the original window and leave the new one, but that shouldn't be necessary.

So I have 2 question:

- How do I solve this?

I have tried `after()` and `update_idletaskes` but none of them seem to work though I may be using the incorrectly.

- What is the problem here?

I thouth tkinter was suposed to be in a loop. When I change the value of `var` shouldn't it loop and re-paint the screen and evaluate `obj.var == False` as `True`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every time you call `paintGui` it is creating a brand new window.  That's because you are calling `Tk()`, creating new widgets, and running a new `mainloop`.  These things only need to happen once, so take them out of the `paintGui` function.

This minimally modified version of your code does what you want.

```
from Tkinter import *

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = True

obj = A()

def meth():
    obj.var = False
    paintGui()

def paintGui():    
    if obj.var == False:
        w.itemconfig("rect", fill="red")


master = Tk()
w = Canvas(master, width=200, height=100)
w.pack()
w.create_rectangle(50, 25, 150, 75, fill="blue", tags="rect")

btn = Button(master, text="Cerrar Mesa",command=meth)
btn.pack(side=BOTTOM)    
mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That pretty much solves it. +1 and accepted answer!